Flutter: Container does not extend behind system bottom navigation/notch
Here is the code for a simple app with a red container:
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }
}

For some reason it does not overlap the bottom system notch:

Note it does overlap the top status bar just fine oddly enough.
How can I fix this so the red container overlaps the bottom system notch?
I have also tried the following, but did not work:
return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: Container(color: Colors.red),
   ),
);

Flutter doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on macOS 14.1 23B2073 darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources


Try to wrap Container with SafeArea and remove extentBody.

Tried that. But bare in mind safe area adds padding to ensure widgets don't overlap system buttons. Not remove.

Use AnnotatedRegion with value: SystemUiOverlayStyle and give systemNavigationBarColor same as you theme color.
AnnotatedRegion(
value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red
),
child: Scaffold(
body: Container(color: Colors.red),
),
)

You can't directly extend Flutter's widgets to cover the bottom system notch on Android apps, but you can use SystemUiOverlayStyle to customize the appearance of the system UI, including the bottom system notch. Here's an example of how to achieve this:
return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        // dark for IOS
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        //These for Android only,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    ); 

